# How to uninstall an Eclipse plugin via command line?

Tags: eclipse

I recently installed Bravo Editor plugin into my Eclipse and it has crashed the installation of Eclipse, now I'm unable to start it.

I've already tried to call it from the command line with `eclipse -clean`, but it's no use.

I'd like to know how it could be uninstalled from the command line.

Answer (score 17):

You can try using [Eclipse Director](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html) and put `com.beck.ep.feature.group` as argument for `-uninstallIU`

The full command for this is:

```
eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -uninstallIU com.beck.ep.feature.group
```

(Use `eclipsec.exe` on Windows.)

You can list the installed features to find the right ID with:

```
eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -listInstalledRoots
```