# Uninstall plugin of eclipse without open eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I have installed a new plugin for eclipse and since then when i opened eclipse after a few seconds it's not responding.
Is there a possible way to get rid of this plugin without open eclipse?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The p2 Director application can do it, but it's not trivial. It's documented (somewhat) at http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html

Another option is to try opening on a brand new workspace; sometimes it's the workspace that causes a problem, not a plug-in by itself.

Final option is to just delete your Eclipse installation (*not* your workspace), and re-extract a clean copy. Since Eclipse "installation" is just a zip/tar extraction, it's not hard to do. You would just need to re-install any third-party plugins that you already had and wanted to keep.

Comment: When you're done re-installing any third-party plugins, zip your customized Eclipse so you can install it (unzip it) again if your Eclipse gets corrupted.

Comment: If you open a new workspace you can go to Installation History and go back to the previous situation.

Answer (score 2):

Open Eclipse installation folder, find *plugins* folder, find the plugin and delete it manually. Then do the same in *features* folder.

Backup everything before, because you might delete something that belongs to Eclipse. This will sometimes require that you run eclipse -clean from your command line/terminal to truly get rid of the plugin.

Comment: Deleting stuff behind Eclipse's back like that is asking for trouble. It doesn't support that and you very easily can corrupt your Eclipse installation.

Comment: True, this action corrupt my kepler installation, I had to install a new version of eclipse

Comment: He asked is there a way to do it manually. Yes, this is the only way and if you know what you are doing it works.

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18492246/623541), you could use Eclipse from the command line with the Eclipse Directory and `-uninstallIU` option.

For example,

```
eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -uninstallIU org.junit
```