# Unable to launch Eclipse neon 4.6 - asks for roo distribution

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-tool-suite, eclipse-neon, roo

I installed Eclipse Neon 4.6 on my linux (Mint) OS. After unsuccessfully trying to install STS (Spring), I uninstalled and reinstalled using the update site -      http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.6/.

Now, when I launch eclipse, it is prompting a dialog that reads "you are trying to generate an spring project but you do not have any Spring roo distribution installed..."

When I click OK, it opens another dialog where it is asking me to point to a Roo installation.

How do I get rid of this so that I can get into Eclipse to install Roo using the marketplace or update site? Has anyone else encountered this problem before?

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: If you're not planning to use Spring Roo support STS I'd suggest you uninstall Roo STS feature. See this to see how to uninstall an eclipse feature https://codeyarns.com/2014/11/07/how-to-remove-feature-or-plugin-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 1):

I installed some default plugins and then the roo plugin kept asking for configuration and couldn't uninstall it from the help menu (because roo was always prompting the configuration menu).

I followed the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491930/how-to-uninstall-an-eclipse-plugin-via-command-line/):

```
$ eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -listInstalledRoots | grep roo
org.springframework.ide.eclipse.roo.feature.feature.group/3.8.3.201612191259-RELEASE
org.springframework.ide.eclipse.roo.feature.source.feature.group/3.8.3.201612191259-RELEASE

$ eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -uninstallIU org.springframework.ide.eclipse.roo.feature.feature.group/3.8.3.201612191259-RELEASE
$ eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -uninstallIU org.springframework.ide.eclipse.roo.feature.source.feature.group/3.8.3.201612191259-RELEASE
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Roo documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/#install-roo-support), you [download Roo](http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/) and then point STS to wherever you installed (extracted) it. My understanding is that Roo operates in conjunction with the IDE, but is a standalone tool.